# Should I create a synchronous or asynchronous POST API when interacting with database?

Tags: python, sql, post

I am creating a POST API to take some test results from the clients and posting it to a database. At what point of time should I send a status 200 back to the client?

1. After I have validated the data in the body of the request?
2. After I have successfully committed the data to the database?

The API call takes less than a second to complete in a typical use-case. I am already creating a fall-back option if the client has a failure, so I am inclined to making it a synchronous request which will take care of all kinds of failures, including data being sent being invalid or the RDS (Database) being down.

I am using Python and SQLAlchemy for developing this API. It's for team's internal use.

Thanks,
Aditya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you have a look at HTTP 202

https://httpstatuses.com/202

This status specifies that `The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed`

This is useful for when you want to return a status that is `intentionally noncommittal` as per the link

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for that, @Jack! I am still wondering though if I should send a status 200 by waiting a few more milliseconds or just send 202 after the validation.

Comment: It's a good question, and II don't think that there's a definitive right answer really. You just have to make a call based on how important it is to have a quick response, and also how much useful error handling you do within the caller if an error response is returned from the api